# How to get a verb connecting two nouns in an Apache OpenNLP parse tree?

Tags: opennlp, parse-tree

What would be a good strategy to find out a verb connecting two nouns in a parse tree, assuming it exists? For example, in this sentence:

> The man called his wife before coming back home.

Given the inputs "man" and "wife", I'd like to get the verb "called".
OpenNLP gives me  a parse tree:

> (TOP (S (NP (DT The) (NN man)) (VP (VBD called) (NP (PRP$ his) (NN wife)) (PP (IN before) (S (VP (VBG coming) (ADVP (RB back)))))) (. home.)))

So I guess this is at least partly a tree navigation question. Maybe 
first isolate all verbs, then test by recursing down, until both nouns are eventually found?

Or try to find the shortest path from one noun to the other and save the verb on the way?

My problem is that I don't know enough about parse tree structure to devise a good strategy. Or should I perhaps use some other (Java) tool?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The task you want to accomplish is really complex. The biggest problem I can see here is about the need to get "a verb connecting two nouns". This is really generic, and as you maybe have already saw parse trees can assume very different (and even "wrong") structures.

If you want a more generic approach to the problem I would suggest you to look for relation extraction. This technique aims at extracting binary (or n-ary) relations from a sentence.
Example tools I would suggest are:

- [RelEx](http://wiki.opencog.org/w/RelEx_Dependency_Relationship_Extractor)
- [MaltParser](http://www.maltparser.org/)
- [ReVerb](http://reverb.cs.washington.edu/)

With the latter one for example you can extract from sentences relations of the form subject-action-object. With regard to your question this will work if the two nouns are respectively the subject and the object of the phrase.

If instead you really want to get the verb connecting two name I think that the navigation of the tree is the most direct solution, but as I pointed out before, it is really difficult to implement given the "imperfection" and the non-standard structure of natural language phrases.

Comment: What you say is right, I noticed that parse trees are sometimes wrong or really complex. Relation extraction is probably the right way to go, so I'll try MaltParser. I was looking at it before, since I need a library, not standalone software. Thanks for pointing me in this direction.

Comment: @Solipsy You're welcome! However you can use ReVerb as a library. I'm using it now in a Java project of mine, and you really just have to set it the pom file (if you use Maven). It integrates directly the functionality of OpenNLP.